# "Result" returning NULL in Asynctask while calling API

Tags: android, apache, android-asynctask, http-post

I am calling an API through POST method and its constantly returning NULL. What could be the possible reason? I have posted the whole code. protected void onPostExecute(Void result) is actually getting NULL.

Comment: Does you request work ? Can you post your AsyncTask code ?

Comment: please post your doInBackground method, since result is posted from there

Answer (score 0):

The structure of what you're doing is not right. You're using an `AsyncTask` with a return type of `Void`. The only possible value of type `Void` is `null`, so that's the only thing you can possibly get back in your `onPostExecute()` method. That's what happens when you `return null` from your `doInBackground()` method.

`Void` is appropriate for when generics force you to use a type, but you don't really need one. So you'd use it only when you don't actually need anything to be returned. In your case, where you're wanting to retrieve something that results from the call, you need a different type.

If all you want is to know whether it's succeeded or not, you could use `Boolean`, and have it return `true` when it succeeds (where you currently have `return null`), and `false` when it fails (in your `catch` blocks).

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah I edited my answer just after you edited your post, so my answer is now a little clearer. It's the `Void` return type that's causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html)

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

so `result` is always `null`.

You must change your asyncTask to return something different than `Void`

Something like :

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Do request
        return "response"; //return request's response as String
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("response")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTP POST is working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid POST req...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its doesn't even give "Invalid POST req..."

Comment: Did you call `execute()`. I edited the code in order to be more simple.

Comment: yep...called it as well. I  am unable to find the actual reason.

Comment: Did you always return something from `doInBackground()` ? If yes print the `result` on the first line of `onPostExecute()`. What is its value ?

Comment: Print it where? since android studio isn't showing console.

Comment: In your logs ! `Log.e("TAG","Things to print");`. Android studio shows logs. Otherwise you can use [logcat](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/logcat.html) to show them.

Comment: Yep. Did. Due to NULL, the app stopped working. Log.e("TAG", result) gives error because of NULL in result.

Comment: You have `null` in `result` because `doInBackground()` return `null`. Check this method.